# using valnilla js why vite did'n include automaticly js file that imported to index.html for build ? while its work fine in dev

Tags: javascript, vite

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="num"></p>
</body>
<script type="module">
    import {sum} from './counter.js'
    const number = sum(2,2)
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = number
</script>
</html>
```

counter.js

```
export function sum(a,b){
    return a+b
}
```

after build
dist/assets/index-74746f.js counter.js already bundle inside it

dist/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="num"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

there is nothing tag script that point to ./assets/index--74746f.js

i know simply i can write <script src="./assets/index--74746f.js . but look not best practice

Comment: Can you add your vite config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after building the index.html contains a proper script tag.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-a1d6a87d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="num"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I couldn't find any option to prevent chunking the inline module script, but on the other hand it's actually not bad when all of your JS including inline one is bundled.
If you don't like a hash in the bundle script you could use:

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(() => {
    return {
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                output: {
                    entryFileNames: 'index.js'
                }
            },
        },
    };
});
```